# run the script according to logical conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, odbc, rodbc

In my data set, I work with groups(stratum) SKU-acnumber-year.
Here little example:

```
df=structure(list(SKU = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L
), stuff = c(8.85947691, 9.450108704, 10.0407405, 10.0407405, 
10.63137229, 11.22200409, 11.22200409, 11.81263588, 12.40326767, 
12.40326767, 12.40326767, 12.99389947, 13.58453126, 14.17516306, 
14.76579485, 15.94705844, 17.12832203, 17.71895382, 21.26274458, 
25.98779894, 63.19760196), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    acnumber = c(137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("SKU", 
"stuff", "action", "acnumber", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

## Very important:

The action column has only two values 0 and 1. As we can see in this example there is 3 observations by stuff of 1 category of action and 18 obs by stuff of zero category.

I need set logic condition.
so, for groups which have from 1 to 4 observations by stuff of 1 category of action, then run script1.r

and for groups which  have >=5 observations by stuff of 1 category of action then must be run script2.r

I would imagine it in this way, the script3.r is created,
with the following content(condition), but I do not know how to correctly set these logical conditions.

```
# i take data from sql
dbHandle <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=;database=;trusted_connection=true")
sql <- paste0(select needed columns)
df <- sqlQuery(dbHandle, sql)



   for groups where from 1-4  observations by stuff of 1 category of action then  C:/path to/скрипт1.r
(or if  groups have from 1-4  observations by stuff of 1 category of action then  C:/path to/script1.r)
    for  groups   where >=5 observations by stuff of 1 category of action then C:/path to/script2.r
( of if groups  have >=5 observations by stuff of 1 category of action then C:/path to/script2.r)
```

How do I implement this? the script.3r runs by  schedule, it will work according to the schedule, in order to run two scripts.
I just do not want to make my Shedule for each script seaprately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `if` logic inside `by`, the method to slice a dataframe by factor(s). And run the other scripts via command line with `system()` calling `Rscript` (assuming the R bin directory is set to your PATH environment variable):

```
by_list <- by(df, df[,c("SKU", "acnumber", "year")], function(sub) {

  if (sum(sub$action == 1) %in% c(1:4))   system("Rscript /path/to/script1.r")
  if (sum(sub$action == 1) >= 5)          system("Rscript /path/to/script2.r")

  return(sub)
})
```

Even better, `source()` the external scripts in main script, making sure to wrap entire process of both scripts in `function()` calls, even adding arguments like specific SKU. Otherwise,`source` *will* run those files. With this approach, you can return output.

```
source("/path/to/script1.r")   # IMPORTS script1_function()
source("/path/to/script2.r")   # IMPORTS script2_function()

by_list <- by(df, df[,c("SKU", "acnumber", "year")], function(sub) {

  current_SKU <- max(sub$SKU)   # OR min(sub$SKU) OR sub$SKU[[1]]

  if (sum(sub$action == 1) %in% c(1:4))  output <- script1_function()
  if (sum(sub$action == 1) >= 5)         output <- script2_function()

  return(output)
})
```

Comment: Tnank you. Parfait, am i right understand you , that i must write my groups here by_list <- by(df, df$SKU, df$acnumber, df$year, function(sub) { Cause you just wrote one group -  SKU, but the stratum SKU-acnumber-year.